# Having trouble getting the output sorted by value

Tags: arrays, bash, sorting

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

output_file="cpumemtest.csv"

# Clear existing content of output file
> $output_file

# Function to get system information
get_system_info() {
  ip=$1
  hostname=$(ssh -n $ip "hostname")

  # Check if SSH connection is successful
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "SSH connection failed for $ip. Skipping." >&2
    return
  fi

  cpu_info=$(ssh -n $ip "lscpu | grep 'CPU(s):'")
  mem_info=$(ssh -n $ip "lsmem | grep 'Total online memory:' || prtconf 2>/dev/null | grep 'Memory Size'")

  # Check if any output is received before printing to the file
  if [[ -n "$cpu_info" || -n "$mem_info" ]]; then
    # Remove lines starting with "NUMA" from cpu_info
    cpu_info=$(echo "$cpu_info" | grep -v 'NUMA')
    echo -e "\n$hostname\n$cpu_info\n$mem_info\n" >> $output_file
  fi
}

# Set the maximum number of concurrent processes
max_processes=10

# Iterate over IP addresses
for i in {1..99}; do
  inconsistent_hosts=()

  # Generate a list of IP addresses
  ips=$(seq -f "10.100.${i}.%g" 1 60)

  # Process each IP sequentially
  for ip in $ips; do
    get_system_info $ip &

    # Limit the number of concurrent processes
    if (( $(jobs | wc -l) >= max_processes )); then
      wait -n
    fi
  done

  # Wait for background processes to finish
  wait
done

echo "Script execution completed. Output saved to $output_file"
```

For each $i value there is a $j range of 1-60 which outputs the total online memory and cpu count for each system.  I wanted the output to group each set of systems in $i in a group and then sorted by total online memory so that the lowest number was at the top. This would allow me to get a list of all the systems in a subnet and see if any have memory issues.  each group in $i should have the same amount of memory and if any doesn't it would appear at the top of the list. Everything I have tried keeps giving me just a list of systems in order but not sorted.